# How do I coalesce my data to reduce the number of different values in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb, rounding, common-table-expression

I have wind speed data with one record per second.  What I have found is that 95% + of the data is in multiples of 0.36 m/s (see the screenshot [Wind Speeds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubgN0.png)), which I'm expecting to find is a result of the way our instrument is configured (still working on that).

What I want to do is round all of the values up or down to a multiple of 0.36, so that I can then generate a probability density visual.

The table in the screenshot comes from this code:

```
WITH freqCTE AS
    (
    SELECT rd.wind_speed,
        COUNT(rd.wind_speed) AS AbsFreq,
        CAST(ROUND(100. * (COUNT(rd.wind_speed)) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raw_data), 3) AS DEC(4,3)) AS AbsPerc
        FROM raw_data AS rd
        GROUP BY rd.wind_speed
    )
SELECT wind_speed, AbsFreq,
    SUM(AbsFreq) OVER(ORDER BY wind_speed ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CumFreq,
    AbsPerc,
    SUM(AbsPerc) OVER(ORDER BY wind_speed ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CumPerc,
    CAST(REPEAT('.',AbsPerc*100) AS VARCHAR(200)) AS Histogram
    FROM freqCTE
    ORDER BY wind_speed;
```

And I know I can round the wind speed like so:

```
ROUND(rd.wind_speed / 0.36, 0) * 0.36
```

I've tried all sorts of things inside the CTE and after the CTE, tried using SET, but I just can't get it to do what I want.  What I really want to see is a table something like:

```
ws36     freq
0.00     4000
0.36     500
0.72     600
1.08     800
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking of a simpler query:

```
SELECT ROUND(rd.wind_speed / 0.36, 0) * 0.36 as wind_speed_036,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM raw_data  rd
GROUP BY wind_speed_036
ORDER BY wind_speed_036;
```